# Wifi in My laptop doesn't work

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-drivers, additional-drivers

I have a laptop model HP 15-ba048au.

Unfortunately, I have to utilize additional usb wifi device for surfing Internet.

Can I wait for the drivers to be installed?

[HP 15-ba048au Wifi Info](https://blog.naver.com/kilsu97/221174208455)

Comment: Please have a look at https://askubuntu.com/q/425155/367990 to find out how to gather all relevant information related to your wireless hardware and include them into your post. Thank you and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: My wireless hardware information is included.